# Trouble getting SQL query to work

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a basic database with a few columns i will show u below

I have a program that allows the user to input if they are Male OR Female OR NULL if they want to

Then they must select a Category such as Love OR Cooking

I tried this Query but it didnt work It displayed other Genders ignoring the Where Gender = M statement

It can only be one Gender but different types of categorys

Any help would be appreciated

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Gender = "M"
AND Category = "Love"
OR Category =  "Cooking"
```

Database

```
Id Name Gender Category 
1   AB    M      Love
2   AC    F      Love
3   AS    M      Cooking
4   SF    Null   Cooking
```

Comment: Try to use single quotes instead: `Gender = 'M'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add brackets around the OR

Something like

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Gender = "M"
AND (Category = "Love"
OR Category =  "Cooking")
```

The way you have it, it would be the same as

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE (Gender = "M"
AND Category = "Love")
OR Category =  "Cooking"
```

Have a look at [Operator precedence](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/sql-syntax.php#PRECEDENC)

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap the categories in brackets in order to tell the query that the gender has to be "M" :

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Gender = "M"
AND (Category = "Love"
OR Category =  "Cooking")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use IN operator here, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM products
WHERE Gender = 'M'
AND Category IN ('Love','Cooking')
```